# Getting rid of derby.log

Tags: java, maven-2, derby

I'm using the Apache Derby embedded database for unit testing in a Maven project. Unfortunately whenever I run the test I end up with the `derby.log` file in the root of the project. The database itself is created in the `target` directory (`jdbc:derby:target/unittest-db;create=true`) so that is not a problem. After consulting the [reference guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefattrib24612.html#rrefattrib24612)  I tried setting the `logDevice` parameter on the JDBC url (`jdbc:derby:target/unittest-db;create=true;logDevice=/mylogs`) but that seems to be for a different log, hence `derby.log` still appears.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get rid of [`derby.log`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdvlp25889.html) file by creating the following class

```
public class DerbyUtil {
    public static final OutputStream DEV_NULL = new OutputStream() {
        public void write(int b) {}
    };
}
```

and setting the JVM system property [`derby.stream.error.field`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefproper33027.html), for example, using the following JVM command-line argument:

```
-Dderby.stream.error.field=DerbyUtil.DEV_NULL
```

[Credit to whom it is due.](http://davidvancouvering.blogspot.com/2007/10/quiet-time-and-how-to-suppress-derbylog.html)

Comment: What if I'm using Derby through Hibernate? Where to I put the line "derby.stream.error.field"?

Comment: In a webapp it's a pain to set system props. Any way around it?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can set things up in your web.xml or spring config to run at startup and do it there.

Comment: Place the above in derby.properties eg. in the root of your project and remeber to use fully qualified name for the class.

Comment: @bmargulies: System.setProperty( "derby.stream.error.field", "DerbyUtil.DEV_NULL" );

Comment: @JoshuaD don't forget to catch the SecurityException you will get if the web container has been implemented to prevent webapps setting system properties, which any good web container should be preventing.

Answer (score 51):

Derby lets you specify the name of the file to which the error log messages are written using the Java system property [`derby.stream.error.file`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefproper33027.html).  The default value is 'derby.log'.

To get rid of `derby.log` during the Maven surefire testing phase, I just add the property definition in the plugin configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>derby.stream.error.file</name>
                <value>target/derby.log</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you shoudl prepend target/ with ${basedir} or else you cannot execute maven from a different dir.

Comment: This works perfectly for unit tests but generally will not produce what you want for integration tests. The reason is that the database is usually in the server (e.g., jetty) which does not inherit the environment from surefire/failsafe.

Comment: You should consider using the ${project.build.directory} variable instead of hard-coding the target folder.                                                                                                                                  <value>${project.build.directory}/derby.log</value>

Answer (score 8):

Include the following in your derby.properties file:

```
derby.stream.error.file=/dev/null
```

( or

```
derby.stream.error.file=\\Device\\Null
```

on Windows)

Comment: \\Device\\Null threw a FileNotFoundException, however using NUL instead did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For integration tests the situation might be a bit more tricky than the simple [surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1933310/3537255) property.
Specifying the property `derby.stream.error.file` in the `maven-failsafe-plugin` will not work as the server environment does not inherit from that plugin (obviously using `maven-surefire-plugin` makes no differences).

Instead you need to modify the actual server start plugin. The following example is for the `maven-jetty-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <!-- Get rid of that missplaced derby.log. -->
            <systemProperty>
                <name>derby.stream.error.file</name>
                <value>${project.build.directory}/derby.log</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note that for some reason we use `systemProperty` and not just `property` as in the surefire solution.

Comment: Sorry, this is exactly what I needed, THIS should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also just set derby home to `target/derby` or `target`via:

```
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", new File("target/derby").getAbsolutePath());
```

and then use the JDBC URL `jdbc:derby:unittest-db;create=true`.
Then derby.log appears in the right folder.

Answer (score 2):

I have came up with another solution. Try this out; it worked for me. What I am doing here is I have changed the System.stream.error.file path and set it to one of the properties present under my property file. Just adding the below given code to your applicationContext.xml file will work.

```
<bean id="setDerbyLog" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetClass"><value>java.lang.System</value></property>
  <property name="targetMethod"><value>setProperty</value></property>
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <value>derby.stream.error.file</value>
      <value>${derby.stream.error.file}</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have access to the configuration, you can execute this before making the connection:

```
System.setProperty("derby.stream.error.field", "MyApp.DEV_NULL");
```

Comment: This is also what I did in an annotated test method with the `@BeforeClass` annotation

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your `derby.log` file problem, (which numerous people have already shown how to resolve), but rather -- a suggestion. Why not use the [derby-maven-plugin](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) for your tests? It places the `derby.log` file under `target/derby`, hence not leaving any litter.

As described in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731178/creating-temporary-database-that-works-across-maven-test-phases/15089028#15089028), you can use Derby as your database via the derby-maven-plugin which I wrote and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/carlspring/derby-maven-plugin) and via Maven Central.