# apache Derby - getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log (Access is denied) when creating new database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am new to Apache Derby database,

When i am trying to crate new database using the following command i am getting the below problem

```
C:\>java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
ij version 10.10
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:Mynewdb;create=true';
Mon Mar 03 20:17:32 IST 2014 Thread[main,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: derby.log
(Access is denied)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Mar 03 20:17:33 IST 2014:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.10.1.1 - (1458268): instance a816c00e-0144-886a-02f2-000000b8d0b0
on database directory C:\Mynewdb with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@11b86e7
Loaded from file:/C:/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/db-derby-10.10.1.1-bin/lib/derby.jar
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
java.runtime.version=1.6.0_23-b05
user.dir=C:\
os.name=Windows 7
os.arch=x86
os.version=6.1
derby.system.home=null
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A file named *derby.log* will be created in the current working directory when you run `ij` (or attempt to use embedded Apache Derby in some other application). From the post, it appears you are executing this from `C:\` and the user you are logged on as does not have write access to that directory: *change to a directory where the user has permission to create a file and retry.*

Note it is possible to suppress this log file (though I have not yet done this myself). See [Getting rid of derby.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004327/getting-rid-of-derby-log). However, suppressing the log file would just result in another failure in your case because the database will be created on the file system relative to the current directory. That is, an attempt to create the directory named `Mynewdb` in the current directory, `C:\`, would also fail for the same reason. It is possible to specify a path for the database to avoid creating in the current working directory:

> ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:/tmp/test_db;create=true';

Comment: My derby network service created the same derby.log file as the one to which the client attempted to write.  Luckily, the file had ownership of the service account and this resulted in an error rather than log file corruption.  I found an option to change the output file, DERBY_OPTS=-Dderby.stream.error.file=derby-client.log bin/ij <<< "exit"

Answer (score 2):

> user.dir=C:\
>
> os.name=Windows 7

Windows 7 (and up?) doesn't let you write files to the root directory in most cases. You should cd to another directory before starting ij. e.g. `cd \Users\YOUR_USER_NAME` and you should be good to go.